# UML/Design Pattern: Need help to check my UML for its correctness

Tags: design-patterns, uml, diagram

The task is:

[image: Photo of the task]

I'm new to UML, so I tried hard and I have these answers (look below). How could I improve them? Where do I have mistakes and what should I edit?

Question 1:

[image: Answer1]

Question 2a:

[image: Answer2a]

Question 2b:

[image: Answer2b]

For the third question I'm confused and I don't know how to draw that. Could you give me suggestions?

Comment: 2a - does each "State" need to override those same methods, or could there be a base "State" class?

Comment: I interpret 2b as suggesting to use interfaces to add new abilities (composition) instead of creating multiple subclasses (inheritance), which would quickly become messy as you add new characters/roles. Any "character" instance could conceivably implement any number of "<<Profession>> interfaces (depending on language, you may or may not be able to extend an interface). Anyone who implements the "<<Medic>>" interface can `heal()`; anyone who implements "<<Soldier>>" is able to `attack(). Abstract the behaviors that vary into separate interfaces (Strategy/Decorator Pattern, I think).

Comment: @mc01 talking about methods - I added by myself. They could be incorrect... So for 2a... I'm so far from patterns, so things that I found - I used it in my work.

Comment: @Antonio112009 The association between classes and actors for me is meaningless and you should avoid to use aggregation: the semantic is not defined in the norm.

Comment: The word extend is not needed: this is the meaning of the arrow. And you teacher request a patterns list, and how you use them. So where are they ?

Answer (score 0):

You've done some good work, but you need to make some corrections. Here are some things I see off the top of my head:

1. Player controls one army; one army is controlled by one player. So your multiplicity values are wrong. Also, no aggregation involved, simple association.
2. Army is composed of multiple units, so composition (black diamond). Also, therefore, an army with zero units is not an army, so an army has to have at least one unit, and a unit can have one and only one army. So, again, your multiplicity values are wrong. Finally, you have the diamond on the wrong end of the association.
3. In your first diagram, Soldier, Medic and Animal do not derive from Unit. If they did, they would be the Unit itself, rather than an attribute of the unit. Rather, they should derive from a Profession class, and Unit should have an association with the Profession class.
4. "Extends" as you have it in your inheritance arrows is what you use in use case diagrams. You don't use that in class diagrams; the fact that the subclass extends the base class is represented by the arrow itself.
5. The third question: this is simply something that the Army class does. So, all you have to do is add a method called, say, PrintArmyList() to the Army class's method list. You're on the right track: you've put "how many units in army" in the method list. What you're missing is you don't define *how* to do that in a class diagram. You simply define *what* the class does. Your prof is throwing you a curve.
6. In your second diagram, Factory pattern is the right pattern to use, but you don't quite have it right (google "factory pattern" and see for yourself). Your Factory class has to have createProfession() defined as abstract (and so needs to be italicized), while each of your concrete methods (Soldier, Medic, Animal) needs to have a concrete implementation of createProfession(). Also, your Profession class is your factory class. Merge the  Profession and Factory classes in your diagram, and associate the Unit class with the Profession class.
7. Your Profession class shouldn't be a composition, just a simple association (no diamond).

An association simply means that one class uses another. An aggregation means that a class "has" a group of classes associated with it. A composition means that the lifetime of the aggregated units is dependent on one another.

A good example of the difference between aggregation and composition is this. Think of a car class. The car has a steering wheel, four tires, two axles, etc. Now, if you were manufacturing cars, the car would have a composition relationship with its tires, axles and so on. If you don't have wheels, you don't have a car, in other words. However, in a junkyard, the car has an aggregation relationship with all these parts. You can pull the wheels off and sell them, and you still have a car, just one with no wheels. So whether it's aggregation or composition depends on the context of the association as much as the nature of the association itself.